# Should I create seperate spring security setup for rest controller and regular controller?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I wanted to create a spring security config for rest controller with OAuth2 but the current project already have a spring security config for regular controller.

Question is: (1) do I make a separate spring sec config with oauth for rest controller? or 
             (2) just include it to the exiting setup?

Any suggestion will be appreciated and any links for a tutorial will be a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling alot, Finally, my config is now working. found out that the config can be in one class or may separate it. Thanks to the config below.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth/examples/sparklr/config/OAuth2ServerConfig.java

the project is also working.